# How to set string date in tablecalendar as event

Tags: flutter, table-calendar

I need to set string date in table calendar as evenloader,anyone can please share demo. it will be very helpful to me thanks.
Api Response:-

```
 "leave_management": [
            {
                "leave_date": "Jan 01, 1970",
                "holiday_type": "partialy_off",
                "holiday_reason": "urgent work at home"
            },
            {
                "leave_date": "Jan 01, 1970",
                "holiday_type": "partialy_off",
                "holiday_reason": "urgent work at home"
            }
        ]
```

i need to show this type of calendar event
[image]

Comment: more detailed description of what you need to do ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which package you are using? Is it https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar ?

Comment: i am using table_calendar.
if you have any other for this task i will implement your.

Comment: Inside table_calender there is support of Event object. You need to convert your leave_management to Event object and just add it in the event list. You can not set date string to event because how it will identify  on which date you want to show this event. So for any calendar library you have to convert it to their event object and set it.

Comment: i need help for it. i have try so many times but i could not set it. could you please share a demo code.